Introduction to Topological Manifold Problem 8-7
I am trying to solve the problem which states,

Suppose $\varphi:\mathbb{S}^1\to\mathbb{S}^1$ is a continuous map. Show that if deg$\varphi\neq\pm1$, then $\varphi$ is not injective.

I think I have an intuitive idea as for why this is true. If the degree is not $\pm1$, then the function wraps around the circle more than once or doesn't wrap around at all. In either cases, there are points such that they get mapped to same image point. However, I am not sure how to prove this using the definitions that are given.

If $\varphi:\mathbb{S}^1\to\mathbb{S}^1$ is a continuous map, we define the $\textbf{$\textit{degree of $\varphi$}$}$ to be the winding number of the loop $\varphi\circ\omega$, where $\omega:I\to\mathbb{S}^1$ is the standard generator of $\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^1,1)$. This integer is denoted by deg$\varphi$.


Suppose $f:I\to\mathbb{S}^1$ is a loop based at a point $z_0\in\mathbb{S}^1$. If $\tilde{f}:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is any lift of $f$, then $\tilde{f}(1)-\tilde{f}(0)$ are both points in the fiber $\epsilon^{-1}(z_0)$, so they differ by an integer. Since any other lift differs from $\tilde{f}$ by an additive constant, the difference $\tilde{f}(1)-\tilde{f}(0)$ is an integer that depends only on $f$, and not on the choice of lift. This integer is denoted by $N(f)$, and is called the $\textbf{$\textit{winding number of $f$}$}$.


Try to consider two cases, depending on whether $\varphi$ is additionally surjective or not.

Hint: Use the lifting properties of $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$.

@Thorgott I proved it for the case for when $\varphi$ is not surjective, but for when $\varphi$ is surjective, I think you need to use the definition of covering maps, which I did not learn yet.

In  your question you use the concept of a lift. How is that possible if you do not know what a covering map is?

@PaulFrost In my textbook, covering map is introduced in Chapter 11 and lift is introduced in Chapter 8. The definition for lift states: If $B$ is a topological space and $\varphi:B\to\mathbb{S}^1$ is a continuous map, a lift of of $\varphi$ is a continuous map $\tilde{\varphi}:B\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi=\epsilon\circ\tilde{\varphi}$ where $\epsilon:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{S}^1$ is defined by $\epsilon(r)=e^{2\pi ir}$.

So you know at least that each $f :  I \to S^1$ has a lift?

@PaulFrost Yes.

Write $f = \varphi \circ \omega$, where $\omega(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$. Note that $f(0) = f(1) = \varphi(1)$.
Let us first consider the case that $\deg \varphi > 1$. This means that $\tilde f(1) - \tilde f(0) = k$ with an integer $k > 1$. The IVT shows that $\tilde f$ attains all values between $\tilde f(0)$ and $\tilde f(1) = \tilde f(0) + k$.
In particular there exists $t_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $\tilde f(t_0) = \tilde f(0) + 1$. Let $z_0 = \omega(t_0)$. Then $z_0 \ne 1$ and
$$\varphi(z_0) = (\varphi \circ \omega)(t_0) = f(t_0) = (\epsilon \circ \tilde f)(t_0) = \epsilon( \tilde f (0) + 1) = e^{2 \pi i(\tilde f(0) + 1)} = e^{2 \pi i\tilde f(0)}e^{2\pi i} \\= e^{2 \pi i\tilde f(0)} = \epsilon(\tilde f(0)) = (\epsilon \circ \tilde f)(0) = f(0) =  \varphi(1)$$
which shows that $\varphi$ is not injective.
The case  $\deg \varphi < -1$ is treated similarly (we find $t_0 \in (0,1)$ such that  $\tilde f(t_0) = \tilde f(0) - 1$).
Let us finally consider the case that $\deg \varphi = 0$. If $\varphi$ is constant, then it is not injective. So let us consider a non-constant $\varphi$ which implies that $\tilde f$ is not constant.
Let $t_0 \in (0,1)$ be a point such that $\tilde f(t_0) \ne \tilde f(0) = \tilde f(1)$. By the IVT there exists $t_1 \in (0,t_0)$ such that $\tilde f(t_1) = (\tilde f(0) + \tilde f(t_0))/2$. Similarly there  exists $t_2 \in (t_0,1)$ such that $\tilde f(t_2) = (\tilde f(1) + \tilde f(t_0))/2$. But then $t_1  \ne t_2$ and $\tilde f(t_1) = \tilde f(t_2)$. With $z_j = \omega(t_j)$ we get $z_1 \ne z_2$ and $\varphi(z_1) = \varphi(z_1)$. Thus $\varphi$ is not injective.

Thank you so much!
